# Sending an email on form submit

Tags: php, forms, email, paypal

I need to send an email to a certain address after a client presses the "Pay with paypal" button (name=submit in the example below). The problem is that form is instantly redirecting me to another page (paypal website) so my code for sending email doesn't get through:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="xxx@company.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Lunch Run ONLINE ORDER">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<PASS-THRU-CODE-HERE>">
        <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
        <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
        <input type=hidden name="return" value="http://www.xxxxx.com/order-confirmation.html">
        <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF">
        <input type="image" src="img/paypal.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with any major credit card!">
</form>
```

I'm open to any ideas, thank you all.

Comment: Will the ajax code get executed before the redirect tho?

Comment: Yes, In this case you also use javascript for Form submission/Post!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. You need to make two ajax calls.

```
<form id="clickonpaypalbutton">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="xxx@company.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Lunch Run ONLINE ORDER">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<PASS-THRU-CODE-HERE>">
        <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
        <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
        <input type=hidden name="return" value="http://www.xxxxx.com/order-confirmation.html">
        <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF">
        <input type="image" src="img/paypal.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with any major credit card!">
</form>



<script>
$('#clickonpaypalbutton').submit(function(event) {
    if(confirm('Confirm?' )) {
        event.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr',
                        data: $(this).serialize(),
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                        }
                });

                $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'path-to-your-email-sending-script',
                        data: $(this).serialize(),
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                        }
                });
    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something to get you started:

You are directly submitting the form on the submit button. Instead use jQuery to run a function when the button is clicked, then submit your form.

Give your form an ID.

```
<form id="form" ... .. </form>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(){  
       //Your email send code here...
      alert("send your email here, then...");
      //submit your form
       $("#form").submit()
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Give "id" to input:submit and use jQuery to send email.
$(document).ready(function(){
     $.ajax({
        url : "sendMail.php",`enter code here
        type: "POST",
        data : "YOURDATE", // "FIELDNAME1=FIELDNAME1VAL&FIELDNAME2=FIELDNAME2VAL etc
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                  alert("Mail Send");
            }
    }); 
});

// sendMail.php`enter code here`

$FIELDNAME1 = $_POST['FILEDNAME1'];
----
---
$FIELDNAMEN = $_POST['FILEDNAMEN'];

// add normal php code for sending mail
```